# FFmpeg overlay image on video with fade-effect

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, frame

Have few doubts wrt following ffmpeg command -
`ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -loop 1 -t 8 -i inputImg.jpg -filter_complex "[1]format=rgba,fade=alpha=1:st=0:d=8,setpts=PTS+10/TB[v1];[0][v1]overlay=x=70:y=100:enable='between(t,2,10)'" -crf 22 -threads 2 -preset ultrafast output.mp4`
1- effect of loop on performance if I don't provide `-t 8` and just use `shortest=1` in overlay filter - will an infinite duration video will be created and only while overlaying shortest one will be selected?
2- what does `setpts` do? - I mentioned `-t 8` - so it loops for 8 seconds. If I do `setpts=PTS+10/TB' does it increase the looped video to a duration of 18s where the fade-in effect is from 10s to 18s? what is there from 0 to 10s in the looped video?
3- how 2 videos are overlaid - are both videos are merged from 0th second?
4- if i want to have a fade effect applied on an image which will be overlaid on my video at say 100th second, then I have to create a looped video of 100s? - how will it affect the performance?
5- can frame_no of main_video[0] be used in looped_video[1]?
6- is there any performance-efficient method/alternative to get the fade-effect applied on an image, based on frame_sequence say, fade_in from frame 30-35?

Answer (score 0):

In order,

*1- effect of loop on performance if I don't provide -t 8 and just use shortest=1 in overlay filter - will an infinite duration video will be created and only while overlaying shortest one will be selected?*

In theory, yes. But at present, there's a bug with `shortest=1`, so don't use it.

*2- what does setpts do?*

It alters timestamps. In your command, it adds 10 seconds to the timestamps so that the image's generated stream has its first timestamps as 10 seconds.

*3- how 2 videos are overlaid - are both videos are merged from 0th second?*

Frames with corresponding timestamps are overlaid i.e. Frame with PTS 10 seconds of image is overlaid on base video frame with PTS 10 seconds.

*4- if i want to have a fade effect applied on an image which will be overlaid on my video at say 100th second, then I have to create a looped video of 100s? - how will it affect the performance?*

No. Duration should be how long you want the video to appear. Use setpts to shift starting time.

*5- can frame_no of main_video[0] be used in looped_video[1]?*

The `enable` switch uses the frame/timestamps from the main video.

*6- is there any performance-efficient method/alternative to get the fade-effect applied on an image, based on frame_sequence say, fade_in from frame 30-35?*

No, same as what you're using. You can use the variables that refer to frame count for setting start `s`, and duration `n`

Comment: Ans 2 - so `setpts` does not affect the duration - only time-stamps are changed? Ans 5 - what I meant was frame_no of stream[0](which is read from the input.txt) be used while evaluating the fade(to calculate the `setpts` dynamically - I want to use enable(n, 30, 35) in overlay filter and accordingly calculate the setpts for fade)?

Comment: Ans 6 - Used this command - `ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -loop 1 -t 1 -i inputImg.jpg -filter_complex "[1]format=rgba,fade=alpha=1:s=0:n=9,setpts=PTS+0/TB[v1];[0][v1]overlay=x=70:y=100:enable='between(n,0,9)'" -crf 22 -threads 2 -preset ultrafast output.mp4'  - but in `s` and `n` in `fade`, probably refer to frames of stream[1]( the looped_video) not stream[0] (main_video read from input.txt) - the o/p of command shared here and one in the question are different.

Comment: *frame_no of stream[0](which is read from the input.txt) be used while evaluating the fade(to calculate the setpts dynamically* --> not possible. `setpts` references the stream it is operating upon.